# How to get the parent node in jQuery event handler?

Tags: jquery

consider this code:

```
<div id="div1">
    <input type="radio" class="a" />
    <input type="radio" class="b"/>
    //....
    <input type="radio"  class="n" />
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <input type="radio" class="a" />
    <input type="radio" class="b"/>
    //....
    <input type="radio"  class="n" />
</div>
```

now i want to bind a delegate event handler to those radio buttons, like this:

```
$("div").on("change","input",myHandler);

function myHandler(e)
{
  alert($(this).prop("class"));
  alert($(e.currentTarget).prop("class"));  // same results...
}
```

my question is : how do i refer to the **div** or get the div **Id** from MyHandler function (it is not by using: $(this), $(e.target), or $(e.currentTarget)) so how to refer the **div**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`event.delegateTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.delegateTarget/). It references the DOM element which you attached the handler to. So to grab its `id` property:

```
function myHandler(e) {
  alert(e.delegateTarget.id);
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fNLvv/)

Comment: No prob, yeah this is a little hidden in the documentation, I firstly saw it by examining the jQuery event object in the console.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has a .parent() function: http://api.jquery.com/parent/

Inside your event handler:

`$(this).parent()`

Comment: Yes this wil work for the very simplistic html that OP posted, though if using nested levels of elements which is often the case for styling, things get more complex.